# Find the smallest positive integer which can be expressed as the sum of four positive squares and divides $2^n +15$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, problem-solving

Find the smallest positive integer which can be expressed as the sum of four positive squares, not necessarily different, and divides $2^n + 15$ for some positive integer $n$.

If you let $K$ be that integer you have, 
$K \equiv 1 \pmod 2$. And if $n \ge 4$ then $16$ divides $K + 1$ but I don't know what to next, hints and solutions would be appreciated.

Taken from the 2009  International World Youth Mathematics Intercity Competition (IWYMIC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest odd natural numbers that are sums of four positive squares are $7=4+1+1+1$ and $13=4+4+4+1$. It is easy to show that $2^n+15$ is never divisible by $7$. But $2^7+15=143$ is divisible by $13$.

Comment: Modulo $7$ the residue class of $2$ generates the subgroup of quadratic residues, and $-15$ is not in that subgroup.  But $2$ is a primitive root modulo $13$.

Comment: I was going to point out that $23 \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ could not be the sum of three squares, therefore must be the sum of four nonzero squares. Also $23 = 8 + 15$ says we could use 23 dividing itself. So, no larger